# Getting MessageLockLost exception on brokered message even though lock was not expired

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have implemented a service bus trigger, my sample code is as below.

```
   public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = 
    "myservicebus:cs")]BrokeredMessage myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
    {
        try
        {   
            if (myQueueItem.LockedUntilUtc <= DateTime.UtcNow)
            {
                log.Info($"Lock expired.");

                return;
            }

            //renew lock if message lock is about to expire.             
            if ((myQueueItem.LockedUntilUtc - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalSeconds <= defaultLock)
            {
                await myQueueItem.RenewLockAsync();

                return true;
            }                

            //Process message logic        

            await myQueueItem.CompleteAsync();           
        }
        catch (MessageLockLostException ex)
        {
            log.Error($"Message Lock lost. Exception: {ex}");

        }
        catch(CustomException ex)
        {
            //forcefully dead letter if custom exception occurs
            await myQueueItem.DeadLetterAsync();
        }           
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error($"Error occurred while processing message. Exception: {ex}");

            await myQueueItem.AbandonAsync();
        }
    }
```

I have set the default lock duration on the queue as 5 minutes. 
I'm getting message lock lost exception for few requests, even though lock was actually not expired.
Request process timings as below:

1. Service bus trigger fired at:               May 07 07:02:14 +00:00 2018 utc
2. LockedUntilUtc in Brokered message  :        May 07 07:07:08.0149905 utc
3. Message lock lost exception occurred at :    May 07 07:02:18 +00:00 2018 utc

Can anybody help me to find actually what is wrong with my code. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not explicitly call `CompleteAsync` and `AbandonAsync` in your code. Those methods will be called by Azure Functions runtime automatically based on the result of your function execution (`Complete` if no exception occurred, `Abandon` otherwise).

Renewing the lock manually shouldn't be necessary either, runtime should manage that for you. If you are running on Consumption plan, the max duration of function execution is 5 minutes (by default) anyway.

Try removing all the plumbing code and leave only `//Process message logic`, see if that helps.

Comment: Mikhail, Thank you very much. your answer is very helpful. I have removed all the `CompleteAsync` and `AbandonAsync` calls and tested the scenario. It's exactly working as you said.
But, I have one requirement, I have slightly modified my code(Added custom exception) I need to handle a custom exception and if that exception occurs, I need dead letter the event forcefully.
In that case what will be the correct way to dead letter the event.
Thanks.

Comment: @Jay Could you create a new question to ask how to DeadLetter on custom exception? I was sure such question exists, but can't find it...

Comment: Mikhail Sure, I will create a new question. Thank you.

Comment: What if I want to log somewhere exception? As for now I am logging exceptions into the ServiceBus topic. If I will remove try catch block, how I gonna then log the exceptions?

Comment: @unsafePtr You may leave `catch`, log the exception and then `throw` to propogate the exception up

Comment: You should make those calls manually if you have auto-complete off.